# Use constant with collection_select with simple_form

Tags: collections, ruby-on-rails-3.2, constants

I have all my constants in constant.rb file, in the initalizers folder.

I have two models: Samples and Patients. Samples can have only one patient but patients can have several samples.

On the new samples form when I want to use one of the constants of the constants.rb, I do a simple select:

```
<%= f.select :consentimentoContacto, DESCONHECIDO %>
```

And it works great.

When I want to use fields from the patient model, I use the collection_select:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:patientID, Patient.all, :id, :date_of_birth ) %>
```

And it also works fine...

What I want to do now, is to use one of the constants, related to the patient model, on the new sample form...

The constant is:

```
ALIMENTOS = ['Sim', 'Nao', 'Desconhecido', 'Nao preenchido']
```

I thought I could do something like this:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:patientID, ALIMENTOS, :id, :patientFeeding ) %>
```

but it returns a "undefined method `patientFeeding' for 'Sim':String" error... What am I doing wrong?

What's the best way to achieve this?

EDIT

I've seen that I should use only select instead of collection_select, because I'm not getting the values from the database. So I tried this:

```
select(:patient, :patientFeeding, ALIMENTOS)
```

and I get this error:

```
undefined method `merge' for ["Sim", "Nao", "Desconhecido", "Nao preenchido"]:Array
```

This seems to be a simple mapping error... but I'm stuck at it for the past two days... Anyone can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do a single selection:

```
<%= f.input :patient, as: :select, collection: ["Sim", "Nao", "Desconhecido", "Nao preenchido"] %>
```

If you want a multiple selection

```
<%= f.input :meeting_days, as: :select, collection: ["Sim", "Nao", "Desconhecido", "Nao preenchido"], input_html: { multiple: true } %>
```

The source code for the collection input [can be found here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/inputs/collection_input.rb).

I've found [this project](https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap) to be a great source of `simple_form` examples.